# Why the value of id="demo2: is still zero evene it is incrementing by one

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So what I am trying to do is, animate using javascript. It is working fine but I also want to show the value of pos(variable) in code, to show the value gradually.

**problem:**
the value of demo2 is not changing even the scope of the variable is same. why not #demo2 not changing.
Please let me know the reason and solution that value of the id #demo2 also change as the value of id #demo changing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    #container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
        background: yellow;
    }

    #animate {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<body>



    function myMove() {
      let id = null;
      const elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
      let pos = 0;
      clearInterval(id);
      id = setInterval(frame, 5);
      function frame() {
        if (pos == 350) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          pos++; 
          elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
          elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pos;
      }
      
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = pos;
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    #container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      background: yellow;
    }
    #animate {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 

    <div id ="container">
      <div id ="animate"></div>
    </div>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
```

```js
function myMove() {
      let id = null;
      const elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
      let pos = 0;
      clearInterval(id);
      id = setInterval(frame, 5);
      function frame() {
        if (pos == 350) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          pos++; 
          elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
          elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pos;
      }
      
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = pos;
    }
```

```css
#container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      background: yellow;
    }
    #animate {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 

    <div id ="container">
      <div id ="animate"></div>
    </div>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
```

```
    <p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="animate"></div>
    </div>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>

    <script>
        function myMove() {
            let id = null;
            const elem = document.getElementById("animate");
            let pos = 0;
            clearInterval(id);
            id = setInterval(frame, 5);
            function frame() {
                if (pos == 350) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                    pos++;
                    elem.style.top = pos + "px";
                    elem.style.left = pos + "px";
                }
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pos;
            }
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = pos;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `frame()` is executed after every other instructions in your function `myMove()`.

If you want to change the value of `#demo2` you have to put it in the same scope as the function `frame()` because that is where the value is updated. Otherwise you will get the value `pos` has when it is initialized.

```js
function myMove() {
    let id = null;
    const elem = document.getElementById("animate");
    let pos = 0;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 350) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + "px";
            elem.style.left = pos + "px";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pos;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: so it means that If there is any kind of wait I t will execute the next lines of code.(what this kind of behavior called?)
can we deal with this, first do this then move next?

Comment: If you want to execute in a certain order you can chain your code using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) but it can complexify your code